# Updating regex pattern to include accented characters isn't working c#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, devexpress

I have the following regex which filters characters to the constraints as defined in the pattern, however I am unable to modify this to include:

> ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ

### Pattern

```
[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[\]\;',./{}|:"<>\? ]+
```

I am using c#, and have tried the following :

```
[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[\]\;',./{}|:"<>\? ]+
```

... however the control I am applying this to, is DevExpress's TextEdit control (the pattern input is displayed below).

[image: pattern]

What pattern can I use that will be valid as this input only accepts valid regex patterns. Invalid patterns dissappear on closing and re-oppening the dialog.

Comment: I think you should try encoding each non latin character to their respective ascii code.

Comment: @antoni - for the applications purpose, I need to accept accents as they are.

Comment: it is going to be same matching once encoded in hexadecimal. give a try with http://www.ascii-code.com/, for instance `Ó` will become `\xD3`.

Comment: Like this simple try in browser console: `/\xD3/.test('Ó');` => true

Comment: I've tried your pattern and there was no errors.